# RabbitMQ consumer connection dies after 90 seconds idle

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have a RabbitMQ task queue and a Pika consumer to consume these tasks (with acks). The problem is that the connection dies after 90 seconds Idle but my tasks will often take longer than that. That means that while tasks are still being computed they are returned to the task queue and never acked.

Using RabbitMQ 3.5.3 and Pika 0.9.14 with the *channel.basic_consume()* method. The connection has a *heartbeat_interval* of 30 seconds.

Consume code:

```
import pika
from time import sleep

RABBITMQ_URL = "amqp://user:pass@my-host.com/my_virtual_host?heartbeat_interval=30"
QUEUE_NAME = "my_queue"


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print body
    sleep(91)  # if sleep value < 90 this code works (even 89)
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)


parameters = pika.URLParameters(RABBITMQ_URL)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue=QUEUE_NAME, durable=True)
channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(callback, queue=QUEUE_NAME)
channel.start_consuming()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    channel.basic_consume(callback, queue=QUEUE_NAME)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/channel.py", line 221, in basic_consume
    {'consumer_tag': consumer_tag})])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1143, in _rpc
    self.connection.process_data_events()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 240, in process_data_events
    if self._handle_read():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 347, in _handle_read
    if self._read_poller.ready():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 43, in inner
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 89, in ready
    self.poll_timeout)
select.error: (9, 'Bad file descriptor')
```

Comment: please post the code that reproduces the problem

Comment: @DerickBailey Thanks for the quick reply. this is my code and my traceback

Comment: Can you trap the exact network connection error and post it?

Comment: Updated code and error to be more general and reproducible. @joshuad2 can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that because you are sleeping for so long, pika cannot respond to heartbeat requests from RabbitMQ, and when this happens, RabbitMQ will close the connection.

The only way around this is to either disable heartbeats or sleep in smaller intervals and run `process_data_events()` continuously so that pika can handle the heartbeats.

**e.g. something like this**

```
def amqp_sleep(connection, time_to_sleep=20):
    remaining = time_to_sleep
    while remaining > 0:
        connection.process_data_events()
        time.sleep(5)
        remaining -= 5
```

Personally though I would go for a library that automatically handles the heartbeats in the background so you don't have to deal with them, e.g. [rabbitpy](https://github.com/gmr/rabbitpy) or my own [amqp-storm](https://github.com/eandersson/amqp-storm).

Comment: Amazing. I'm surprised that the pika documentation doesn't mention this. I'll definitely try these libraries next time I'm using rabbitmq. For this project I've already abandoned rabbitmq in favor of a simple redis queue.